# Remove an element from ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby hash as follows. The value is a string with comma seperated.

```
def fruits
  f = {"fruits" => "apple, orange, grapes"}
end
```

How can i remove apple from this value. SOmetimes it can contain only "apple" value only.

```
f = {"fruits" => "apple"}
```

So doing gsub throws nil error when doing like below.

```
f.each{|k,v| v.gsub!("apple","").gsub!("apple,","")}
```

Comment: `gsub!` can sometimes return `nil`. This is described in its documentation.

Comment: Wouldn't your value-string be better off as an array?

Comment: @iceツ These values are coming from an api as string with comma seperated.

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with hashes. It's basically just asking how to remove a substring from a string.

Comment: @rubyist do you have to keep the API's format in _your_ code?

Answer (score 2):

What about treat it as an array?

```
f['fruits'] = f['fruits'].split(', ').reject { |w| w == 'apple' }.join(', ')
```

Comment: You can use `grep_v` too.

Comment: @iceツ starting with Ruby 2.3 only.

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution to remove any number of fruits:

```
f = {"fruits" => "apple, orange, grapes"}
f.merge({'fruits' => 'apple'}) do |_, v1, v2|
  [v1, v2].map { |v| v.split(', ') }.reduce(:-).join(', ')
end
#⇒ "orange, grapes"
```

Comment: `(v1.split(', ') - v2.split(', ')).join(', ')` :)

Comment: Or "better" `[v1, v2].map{|v| v.split(', ')}.reduce(:-).join(', ')` :)

Comment: It was a joke! :notlikethis:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev indeed, it was. Any time I could put a smiley into my code I do.

Comment: Oh god, I hope you don't use extended unicode in your names :) Like `hello❗️ = 'hello world'`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Of course I do. And [Mike Perham does](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/13443beb06106ea28ef8641994e99699144b8693/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L269), btw.

Comment: yeah-yeah, you posted this one already. And I already made that joke, I believe :)